# What is the Delphi/Pascal equivalent to MS-Excel's NormDist function?

Tags: excel, delphi, distribution

I am porting a liquid chromatography simulator from MS-Excel (it works well) to Delphi so I can have an executable I can share with students and working chromatographers. The [`NormDist` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/normdist-function-126db625-c53e-4591-9a22-c9ff422d6d58) is central to that task.  It seems that there is no Normal Distribution function (NormDist) native to Delphi.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help folks.

In the end, I decided to write my own (limited) function for Probability Density (Normal Distribution).

There is no error checking so this is not a general solution, but it works well for my limited purposes.

The extended result returned is important for small values of Standard Deviation (StdDev) and larger values of X else there is a floating point overflow error message.

```
function NormalDistribution(X: extended; Mean, StdDev: double):extended;
var  e,Sqrt2Pi: extended;
begin
  e := 2.71828182845905;
  Sqrt2Pi := 2.506628274631;
  Result := (1/(StdDev*Sqrt2Pi))*Power(e, -0.5*Power(((X-Mean)/StdDev), 2));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not that deep into mathematics I simply used the keywords `NormDist Excel Delphi` on a search engine, which led me to [this unit](https://github.com/TurboPack/SysTools/blob/master/source/StStat.pas) having exactly the same function with the same parameters [as in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/normdist-function-126db625-c53e-4591-9a22-c9ff422d6d58). Better download [all the units](https://github.com/TurboPack/SysTools/tree/master/source), since at least 2 others are needed.

An amalgamation of all needed code would be:

```pas
const
  sqrt2pi = 2.5066282746310005; {sqrt(2*pi)}

function Erfc(X : Single) : Single;
var
  t, z, ans : Double;
begin
  z := abs(X);
  t := 1.0/(1.0+0.5*z);
  ans := t*exp(-z*z-1.26551223+t*(1.00002368+t*(0.37409196+t*(0.09678418+
    t*(-0.18628806+t*(0.27886807+t*(-1.13520398+t*(1.48851587+
    t*(-0.82215223+t*0.17087277)))))))));
  if (X >= 0.0) then
    Result := ans
  else
    Result := 2.0-ans;
end;

function NormSDist(Z : Single) : Single;
const
  sqrt2 = 1.41421356237310;
begin
  Result := 1.0-0.5*Erfc(Z/sqrt2);
end;

function NormDist(X, Mean, StandardDev : Single;
  Cumulative : Boolean) : Single;
var
  Z : Extended;
begin
  if (StandardDev <= 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid parameter');
  Z := (X-Mean)/StandardDev;
  if (Cumulative) then
    Result := NormSDist(Z)
  else
    Result := exp(-Z*Z/2.0)/(StandardDev*sqrt2pi);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks AmigoJack.  ;)  I went to google and looked but somehow missed what you found.  I'll have to make my own function of course but this points me in the right direction.  I'll be applying the function to each member of a 20,000+member array (X-value) to obtain the Y-Value when the mean and stddev varies with each (up to 20) different arrays - and then plot all the arrays on a chart (graph) that looks like a chromatogram.  Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can upvote and accept answers, as said in the [tour].

Comment: For those wondering why the above function Erfc(x) works: This is a Chebyshev approximation of the Error Function with fractional error everywhere below 1.2E-7. The original source is the book by W.H. Press et al., Numerical Recipes - The Art of Scientific Computing